# Why is the orthogonality of complex functions defined with the integration between its complex conjugate?

Tags: complex-integration, orthogonality

As stated in the  title, I am not quite understand the orthogonality of complex functions.

For example, for the following function family:
\begin{equation}
\phi_k(x)=e^{ikx},
\end{equation}
its orthogonality is defined using the integration between
\begin{equation}
\phi_l(x)=e^{-ilx},
\end{equation}
in [0, 2$\pi$].
This way, the functions used are belonging to two different families, how can it be utilized to define orthogonality of one family of functions?

Comment: It may be useful to draw a comparison with regular vectors. We tend to colloquially refer to orthogonality in that case in terms of a 'dot product between vectors'. But what's really going on is a multiplication of column and row vectors (analogous to the two different 'families', as you put it, of complex exponentials). Additionally, you also have a way to go between the two families (complex conjugation in your case, transposition in the vector case.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not different families. It is just their complex conjugates.

This is usual in complex vector spaces. It stems from the very definition of the usual inner or hermitean product $<..,..>:\mathbb{C}^n\times\mathbb{C}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{C} $:
$$<(a_1,a_2,...,a_n),(b_1,b_2,...,b_n)>=a_1\overline{b_1}+a_2\overline{b_2}+...+a_n\overline{b_n}$$
The reason lying behind this apparent "peculiarity", is that if we try to "mimic" the usual inner product of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and define 
$(..,..):\mathbb{C}^n\times\mathbb{C}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ through
$$<(a_1,a_2,...,a_n),(b_1,b_2,...,b_n)>=a_1b_1+a_2b_2+...+a_nb_n$$
(i.e. without using a complex conjugation on the second variable), we end up with a symmetric, non-degenerate, bilinear form on $\mathbb{C}^n$, which however is not an inner (or: hermitean) product in $\mathbb{C}^n$.

What i am trying to say here, is that the conjugation underlies any kind of "measurable" quantification in complex numbers. (measurable here stands for something producing a real value as an indication of magnitude, i.e. a number which can directly be tested to the experiment). Remember that even the magnitude of a complex number $z$ is given by the square root of $z\bar{z}$ and not by the square root of $z^2$.

Comment: Yes, I know this. But why bother using its conjugation, not itself?

Comment: by definition, an hermitian product in a complex space has to satisfy: $<a,b>=\overline{<b,a>}$. If you don't use the conjugate then it cannot be satisfied.

Comment: @KonstantinosKanak0glou Doesn’t this beg the question, though? You’re then left with what’s essentially the equivalent question of why that particular property is important.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you’ve accepted an answer, I’ll offer a slightly different explanation.

Inner products are closely related to norms via a formula you probably already know: $$\|\mathbf v\|^2 = (\mathbf v, \mathbf v).$$ It would be nice if this norm was compatible with an existing norm that the scalar field might have, in particular, we’d like $$\|z\mathbf v\| = |z|\|\mathbf v\|$$ to hold. Now, we like complex numbers to have nonnegative real-valued norms for various reasons, so we have $|z|^2 = z\overline z$. It doesn’t work if you simply square $z$. That conjugate percolates back up through the definitions of complex vector norms and inner products to maintain this consistency.